# Get and update Data from Firestore - Problems

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

For my app, I have a lot of occasions, where I need to retrieve and write data to Firestore.
I am able to write new data and to get and display data. I can also overwrite data in one class, but having troubles right now in another one despite using the same method.

```
    FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    FirebaseUser currUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    DocumentReference userDocRef = db.collection("Users").document(currUser.getEmail());
    //access current values saved under this user
    userDocRef.get().addOnSuccessListener(new 
    OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
            User currentUser = documentSnapshot.toObject(User.class);
            warmups_skipped = currentUser.getWarmupsSkipped()+1;
            Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot successfully retrieved! " + warmups_skipped);

        }
    });
```

I can see in logCat that the local variable is being changed. All good so far.
Then I call this method immediately after:

```
    FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    FirebaseUser currUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    DocumentReference userDocRef = db.collection("Users").document(currUser.getEmail());
    Map<String, Object> update = new HashMap<>();
    update.put(WARMUPSSKIPPED, getWarmups_skipped());
        userDocRef
                .set(update, SetOptions.merge()).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Document has been saved");
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Document could not be saved");
        }
    });
    }
```

Also here I get the TAG message displayed, but nothing gets changed in FireStore. I use the exact same second method in another class, where I do not check for, what is already online, but simply overwrite it.
Really appreciate the help!

Comment: Is you checked in `OnFailureListener` any exceptions ?

Comment: I dont understand what you mean hereby, im sorry. I dont get any exceptions, no.

Comment: Which log message shows? `Log.d(TAG, "Document has been saved");` or `Log.d(TAG, "Document could not be saved");`? Note that in the second case you're being passed an `Exception`, which you're currently ignoring. I'd recommend at the very least logging it: `Log.d(TAG, "Document could not be saved: "+e.toString());`

Comment: "Document successfully retrieved" (and the correctly updated number) and then for the second piece of code it shows "Document has been saved"

Comment: The weird thing is, if I call only the second piece of code and just overwrite it without caring about the content, then it DOES update the number I want to change from 0 to 1. If I repeat the process, however, nothing happens again and the value stays at 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I figured it out eventually. Apparently I cannot have these two actions separate, so I put the second method inside the first one and now it seems to work. Not entirely sure why, though, cause the variables are class variables and should be accessible from both methods. If anyone else has that problem, here is how it works for me now:

```
    FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    FirebaseUser currUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    final DocumentReference userDocRef = db.collection("Users").document(currUser.getEmail());
    //access current values saved under this user
    userDocRef.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
            User currentUser = documentSnapshot.toObject(User.class);
            warmups_skipped = currentUser.getWarmupsSkipped()+1;
            Map<String, Object> update = new HashMap<>();
            update.put(WARMUPSSKIPPED, warmups_skipped);
            userDocRef
                    .set(update, SetOptions.merge()).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Document has been saved");
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Document could not be saved" +e.toString());
                }
            });
            Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot successfully retrieved! " + warmups_skipped);
        }
    });
```